# Is it Permissible Using Plural Of Respect for ALLAH in Supplication in mother tongue?

Tags: allah, respect

My mother tongue is **HINDI** so I make Supplication in Hindi not in prayer but throughout the day so my question is in Hindi there is word called 
"तू" pronounced as "Tu"
 and 
another word "आप" pronounced as "aap"

Word Tu represent / address a strict singular person 
Word  aap represent /address more than one person  **but sometimes it is also used as plural of respect in Hindi as used by many scholar of hindu scripture**

So my question is when I make supplication which word I should use I searched and founded out that Muslim scholar in India says to use word Tu but I feel that I am disrespecting ALLAH (SWT) but I fear to use word aap so what should I use and one more thing  in Hindi Translation of Quran plural of respect is used.

Comment: Literally we use the singular: when we say Oh Allah  (Yaa Allah) يا الله, Oh Lord (Yaa Rabb) يا رب. Maybe a workaround is adding an attribute, like Oh most merciful of the mercifuls Oh Allah (Yaa arham ar-Rahimeen ya Allah) يا أرحم الراحمين يا الله.  I have some reservation for using the plural ... but have no answer right now.

Comment: @Uma ah well in Hindi it can be used for any person out of respect or for  gatherings of people

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Mufti Akmal answered this question for example [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ZGs5rRiiv2M) and [here](http://www.dailymotion.com/video/x4pl3l6) regarding the usage of آپ (Aap) in Urdu, I guess it would be a similar case for Hindi:

He says that it is *permitted* but *not appropriate* to call Allah as *Aap* because there is an ambiguity in it whether the singular or plural is meant.

He cites that while Allah himself has used the plural pronoun of majesty to refer to himself in Quran (such as [إِنَّا](http://corpus.quran.com/wordmorphology.jsp?location=(97:1:1))):

However throughout the Quran and Hadith whenever it has been related how a Prophet or any person has addressed or prayed to Allah then that person has used the *singular* pronoun (such as [إِيَّاكَ](http://corpus.quran.com/wordmorphology.jsp?location=(1:5:1))) and not the plural form, and this is to emphasize Allah's Oneness and so تو (Tu) should be used to refer to Allah, and this is the correct and respectful way to do it as has been taught to us in the Quran.

Answer (score 0):

Yes.

Even within the Quran, Allah has used the royal plural form to address Himself on many a occasion.

> وَلَقَدْ خَلَقْنَا الْإِنسَانَ وَنَعْلَمُ مَا تُوَسْوِسُ بِهِ نَفْسُهُ
>   ۖ وَنَحْنُ أَقْرَبُ إِلَيْهِ مِنْ حَبْلِ الْوَرِيدِ
>
> And We have already created man and know what his soul whispers to
>   him, and **We** are closer to him than [his] jugular vein. 
>    [(Quran 50:15)](https://quran.com/50/16)

And

> ثُمَّ إِنَّ عَلَيْنَا حِسَابَهُم
>
> Then indeed, upon **Us** is their account. 
>  ([Quran 88:26](https://quran.com/88/26))

Comment: The issue with your examples is that Allah () is speaking about Himself which certainly is appropriate, while if we read verses of supplication we find Him always addressed in singular "ربنا" (Oh our Lord), "ربي" (My Lord) etc.